# Angular save watch expression from attr in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to pass some html to attr in directive, the problem i have that what i do does not save binding it is only display the initial value, how can i accomplish data binding here?

```
function link( $scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, transclude ) {
    $scope.dropDownClass = attrs.ddClass || 'default';
    var main = $compile(attrs.main)($scope);
    elem.find('button').first().append(main);
  }

<my-drop-down main='<a><img src="images/flags/en.png" alt="en"/>{{name}}</a>'>
 <li><a><img src="images/flags/en.png" alt="en"/>En</a></li>
</my-drop-down>
```

I want the {{name}} to still be binding to my controller.

http://plnkr.co/edit/IrF1dIZslCEQf0FOfNJi?p=preview

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle? I have a couple ideas but don't know off the top of my head and would like to.. well, fiddle with your working problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I took a quick look. From what I could see, the main attribute is being evaluated *before* your `attr` lookup. So, your actually compiling `<a>World</a>` *not* `<a>{{name}}</a>`.

I don't think there is a way to tell angular not to evaluate an attribute (there is [ngNonBindable](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable) for markup, but that doesn't help us). I see two solutions for your problem.

**Option #1**: You could pull out your desired template string from an attribute and, instead, attach it to your scope in `MainCtrl`. That looks like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/M6GZJDVHuW8op2Zo11mJ?p=preview

```
// Markup:
<my-drop-down> ...

// MainCtrl:
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.main = '<a>{{name}}</a>';
});

// Then, in your directive link:
function link($scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, transclude ) {
  $scope.dropDownClass = attrs.ddClass || 'default';
  // Use scope.main, instead of attrs.main:
  var main = $compile($scope.main)($scope);
  elem.find('button').first().append(main);
}
```

**Option #2**: If you wanted to keep the passing of the template string in an attribute we cannot, as far as I can tell, use curly braces and expect them to be passed through as curly braces. So, we could try to use something else that is unique enough for our code. I chose `%%`, but it could be anything you wanted, really. That would look like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/760CFsq9sF9lIBHgO2Ic?p=preview

```
// Markup:
<my-drop-down main="<a>%%name%%</a>">

// Then, in your directive link:
function link($scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, transclude ) {
  $scope.dropDownClass = attrs.ddClass || 'default';
  // Replace our template string and compile that w/ braces:
  var tpl = attrs.main.replace(/%%([a-z]+)%%/g, '{{$1}}');
  var main = $compile(tpl)($scope);
  elem.find('button').first().append(main);
}
```

There are other options you could take, like creating an isolate scope, etc. but they require more refactoring of your code. The above two seem to be the easiest to drop-in.

Comment: Thanks man, i realy appreciate your answer, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that when your link function is executed, `name` is already interpolated.

In addition to what @rgthree said you could also use the `compile` function on directive to only call `var compiled = $compile(tAttrs.main)` and then in the link function call the return value with the scope `var main = compiled($scope)`:

```
compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
      var compiled = $compile(tAttrs.main);
      return function( $scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, transclude ) {
          $scope.dropDownClass = attrs.ddClass || 'default';
          console.log(3);
          var main = compiled($scope);
          elem.find('button').first().append(main);
      }
    },
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rve8fBMgWseyHKo3Weiv?p=preview)